# NPE in Drag and Drop

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx, parseint, javafx-8

I'm tested this code in Windows JVM 7_25 it works well.

```
import java.util.Random;  
import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;  
import javafx.event.EventHandler;  
import javafx.scene.Node;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;  
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;  
import javafx.scene.input.Dragboard;  
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;  
import javafx.scene.input.TransferMode;  
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;  
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;  
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  
public class DraggableFlowPane extends Application {  
    @Override  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {  
        final FlowPane root = new FlowPane();  
        final Random rng = new Random();  
        final int NUM_NODES = 120;  
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NODES; i++) {  
            int red = rng.nextInt(256);  
            int green = rng.nextInt(256);  
            int blue = rng.nextInt(256);  
            Node node = createNode();  
            node.setStyle(String.format("-fx-background-color: rgb(%d, %d, %d);", red, green, blue));  
            root.getChildren().add(node);  
        }  
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 500));  
        primaryStage.show();  
    }  
    private Node createNode() {  
        final BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();  
        bp.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {  
                Dragboard db = bp.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);  
                ClipboardContent clipboard = new ClipboardContent();  
                final int nodeIndex = bp.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()  
                        .indexOf(bp);  
                clipboard.putString(Integer.toString(nodeIndex));  
                db.setContent(clipboard);  
                event.consume();  
            }  
        });  
        bp.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {  
                boolean accept = true;  
                final Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();  
                if (dragboard.hasString()) {  
                    int incomingIndex = Integer.parseInt(dragboard.getString());  
                    int myIndex = bp.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()  
                            .indexOf(bp);  
                    if (incomingIndex == myIndex) {  
                        accept = false;  
                    }  
                } else {  
                    accept = false;  
                }  
                if (accept) {  
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);  
                }  
            }  
        });  
        bp.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {  
                boolean success = false;  
                final Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();  
                if (dragboard.hasString()) {  
                    int incomingIndex = Integer.parseInt(dragboard.getString());  
                    final Pane parent = (Pane) bp.getParent();  
                    final ObservableList<Node> children = parent.getChildren();  
                    int myIndex = children.indexOf(bp);  
                    final int laterIndex = Math.max(incomingIndex, myIndex);  
                    Node removedLater = children.remove(laterIndex);  
                    final int earlierIndex = Math.min(incomingIndex, myIndex);  
                    Node removedEarlier = children.remove(earlierIndex);  
                    children.add(earlierIndex, removedLater);  
                    children.add(laterIndex, removedEarlier);  
                    success = true;  
                }  
                event.setDropCompleted(success);  
            }  
        });  
        bp.setMinSize(50, 50);  
        return bp;  
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        launch(args);  
    }  
}
```

When I tested the same code on Linux with JVM 7_25 I get this error stack:

```
    Executing com.javafx.main.Main from /home/rcbandit/Desktop/test/DX-57DC/dist/run652386450/DX-57DC.jar using platform /opt/jdk1.7.0_25/bin/java  
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:58)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:52)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.fireEvent(Scene.java:2631)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.processTargetEnterOver(Scene.java:2780)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$6100(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DropTargetListener.dragEnter(Scene.java:2523)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$1.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:63)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$1.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:54)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.handleDragEnter(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:54)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleDragEnter(GlassViewEventHandler.java:395)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleDragEnter(View.java:692)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyDragEnter(View.java:1005)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystemImpl(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystem(GtkDnDClipboard.java:24)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard.flush(SystemClipboard.java:28)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance.flush(ClipboardAssistance.java:34)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.flush(QuantumClipboard.java:197)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startDrag(QuantumToolkit.java:1195)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.dragDetectedProcessed(Scene.java:2652)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.process(Scene.java:2713)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$8700(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3344)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:58)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:52)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.fireEvent(Scene.java:2631)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.processTargetEnterOver(Scene.java:2780)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$6100(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DropTargetListener.dragOver(Scene.java:2534)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:126)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassViewEventHandler.java:422)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleDragOver(View.java:701)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyDragOver(View.java:1010)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystemImpl(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystem(GtkDnDClipboard.java:24)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard.flush(SystemClipboard.java:28)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance.flush(ClipboardAssistance.java:34)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.flush(QuantumClipboard.java:197)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startDrag(QuantumToolkit.java:1195)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.dragDetectedProcessed(Scene.java:2652)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.process(Scene.java:2713)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$8700(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3344)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:58)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:52)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.fireEvent(Scene.java:2631)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.processTargetEnterOver(Scene.java:2780)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$6100(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DropTargetListener.dragOver(Scene.java:2534)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:126)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassViewEventHandler.java:422)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleDragOver(View.java:701)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyDragOver(View.java:1010)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystemImpl(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystem(GtkDnDClipboard.java:24)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard.flush(SystemClipboard.java:28)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance.flush(ClipboardAssistance.java:34)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.flush(QuantumClipboard.java:197)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startDrag(QuantumToolkit.java:1195)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.dragDetectedProcessed(Scene.java:2652)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.process(Scene.java:2713)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$8700(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3344)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:58)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:52)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.fireEvent(Scene.java:2631)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.processTargetEnterOver(Scene.java:2780)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$6100(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DropTargetListener.dragOver(Scene.java:2534)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:126)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassViewEventHandler.java:422)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleDragOver(View.java:701)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyDragOver(View.java:1010)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystemImpl(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystem(GtkDnDClipboard.java:24)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard.flush(SystemClipboard.java:28)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance.flush(ClipboardAssistance.java:34)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.flush(QuantumClipboard.java:197)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startDrag(QuantumToolkit.java:1195)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.dragDetectedProcessed(Scene.java:2652)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.process(Scene.java:2713)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$8700(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3344)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:58)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:52)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.fireEvent(Scene.java:2631)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.processTargetEnterOver(Scene.java:2780)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$6100(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DropTargetListener.dragOver(Scene.java:2534)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:126)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassViewEventHandler.java:422)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleDragOver(View.java:701)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyDragOver(View.java:1010)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystemImpl(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystem(GtkDnDClipboard.java:24)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard.flush(SystemClipboard.java:28)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.ClipboardAssistance.flush(ClipboardAssistance.java:34)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumClipboard.flush(QuantumClipboard.java:197)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startDrag(QuantumToolkit.java:1195)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.dragDetectedProcessed(Scene.java:2652)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.process(Scene.java:2713)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$8700(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3344)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3168)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1900(Scene.java:3123)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1563)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2265)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:250)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:173)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:292)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:528)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:922)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$3$1.run(GtkApplication.java:82)  
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)  
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NumberFormatException: null  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:454)  
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:58)  
        at com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC$2.handle(DX57DC.java:52)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:69)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:217)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:170)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:38)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:37)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:35)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:92)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:53)  
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:33)  
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:171)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.fireEvent(Scene.java:2631)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.processTargetEnterOver(Scene.java:2780)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DnDGesture.access$6100(Scene.java:2607)  
        at javafx.scene.Scene$DropTargetListener.dragOver(Scene.java:2534)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:126)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler$4.run(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassSceneDnDEventHandler.java:117)  
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleDragOver(GlassViewEventHandler.java:422)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleDragOver(View.java:701)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyDragOver(View.java:1010)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystemImpl(Native Method)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkDnDClipboard.pushToSystem(GtkDnDClipboard.java:24)  
        at com.sun.glass.ui.SystemClipboard.flush(SystemClipboard.java:28)  

................................................................
```

(and more)

The content of `int incomingIndex = Integer.parseInt(dragboard.getString());` is Null

Can you tell me how I can fix this issue or rewrite the code?

Comment: NPE is the type of joke that does not believe in your program.

Comment: I would start by producing a cut down example and highlighting the offending line for us

Comment: Well, I get 'java.lang.NumberFormatException: null'

Comment: It looks like a bug or a difference in behaviour in the ClipBoard implementation, which is different across platform => submit a bug report on Jira.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check you `dragboard.hasString()`. Definitely it should return `FALSE` in case of `dragboard.getString()` is *null*. So, you never reach `int incomingIndex = Integer.parseInt(dragboard.getString());`, because you won't pass trough `if (dragboard.hasString())`

If you can't find the problem paste your `Dragboard` class implementation.

EDIT:

Well this will be more robust:

```
private Node createNode() {  
        final BorderPane bp = new BorderPane();  
        bp.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {  
                Dragboard db = bp.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);  
                ClipboardContent clipboard = new ClipboardContent();  
                final int nodeIndex = bp.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()  
                        .indexOf(bp);  
                clipboard.putString(Integer.toString(nodeIndex));  
                db.setContent(clipboard);  
                event.consume();  
            }  
        });  
        bp.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {  
                boolean accept = true;  
                final Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();  
                if (dragboard.hasString()) {  
                  try {
                    int incomingIndex = Integer.parseInt(dragboard.getString());  
                    int myIndex = bp.getParent().getChildrenUnmodifiable()  
                            .indexOf(bp);  
                    if (incomingIndex == myIndex) {  
                        accept = false;  
                    }  
                  } catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
                    //handle null or not number string in clipboard
                    accept = false;
                  }
                } else {  
                    accept = false;  
                }  
                if (accept) {  
                    event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);  
                }  
            }  
        });  
        bp.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {  
            @Override  
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {  
                boolean success = false;  
                final Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();  
                if (dragboard.hasString()) {  
                  try {
                    int incomingIndex = Integer.parseInt(dragboard.getString());  
                    final Pane parent = (Pane) bp.getParent();  
                    final ObservableList<Node> children = parent.getChildren();  
                    int myIndex = children.indexOf(bp);  
                    final int laterIndex = Math.max(incomingIndex, myIndex);  
                    Node removedLater = children.remove(laterIndex);  
                    final int earlierIndex = Math.min(incomingIndex, myIndex);  
                    Node removedEarlier = children.remove(earlierIndex);  
                    children.add(earlierIndex, removedLater);  
                    children.add(laterIndex, removedEarlier);  
                    success = true;  
                  } catch(java.lang.NumberFormatException e) {
                    //handle null or not number string in clipboard
                  }
                }  
                event.setDropCompleted(success);  
            }  
        });  
        bp.setMinSize(50, 50);  
        return bp;  
    }
```

Comment: Dragboard is a part of a JavaFX package and I cannot edit this code. Is there other solution - for example can I implement this code with other type of buffer. https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2565418

Comment: This post is interesting: I was doing the easiest thing here. If you have other drag and drop behavior implemented, which you likely do, you should probably do something slightly different so as not to "confuse" the drag and drop if you dragged from somewhere else in the UI and dropped on one of the child nodes on the FlowPane. I would probably use an ObjectProperty<Node> to store the "currently dragged node"; ensure it is null if no drag is in process and set it only when the drag starts. Then use that to test when in the dragOver and dragDropped handlers.

Comment: Try to extend your check to `if (dragboard.getString() != null && dragboard.hasString()) {` Or create inner `if` inside the first `if` body and implement special handler for the _null_ case.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an idea how the null case must be handled when NPE occurs. Could you edit your answer with the proper implementation, please?

Answer (score 5):

It appears that you pass `null` as an int, and `null`cannot be converted into an `Integer` (or int)

```
int incomingIndex = Integer.parseInt(dragboard.getString());
```

Check the output of `dragboard.getString()`.

Comment: The content of `dragboard.getString()` in `null`

Comment: Thats the reason the exception ocurrs. You need to find out, why it's `null`. But that's another question, at least you could confirm the `NPE`.

Comment: No, can't figure our why it works on windows but not on linux. Maybe you can reduce the code "overhead" down to a small sample to reproduce the error. The smaller the example the "easier" it is for us to find the problem/reason. Then open another question with the smaller example and try your luck again ;)

Answer (score 2):

Peter,

I was going through this link to understand more about the drag and drop functionality. - http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/drag_drop/jfxpub-drag_drop.htm. 
From the examples they have given there, you seem to have done the expected things.

Coming to your actual code:
I would try to understand whether I am putting a null into the ClipboardContent object in the setOnDragDetected({});
The ClipboardContent class extends a HashMap - http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html.

If the nodeIndex you're trying to get isn't of the DataFormat.PLAIN_TEXT, the clipboard.putString() may not actually put the index in the hashmap. Refer to the statement - "Setting this value to null effectively clears it from the clipboard." in the javadoc and confirm whether this isn't happening.

The putString method returns a Boolean as True if the 'put' operation was successful.

I would print these two things(output of 'putString()', and value of the 'nodeIndex') to investigate what's going wrong.

-Regards, 
Ravi.